# Webhook в telegram. Как получать сообщения?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Создал бота в telegram, настроил его на Wehook к моему сайту, он при каждом сообщении делает запрос на сайт, но я не пойму как получить сообщения которое пришло боту, т.к. при включенном Webhook функция getUpdate заблокирована. В интернете все говорят установить [Библиотеку](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) которая ставиться через консоль, которой у меня нет, я могу только версию php менять на хостинге, управлять phpmyadmin и делать cron задачи (не знаю что это).

setWebhook
Этот метод необходим для задания URL вебхука, на который бот будет отправлять обновления. Каждый раз при получении обновления на этот адрес будет **отправлен HTTPS POST с сериализованным в JSON объектом Update.** При неудачном запросе к вашему серверу попытка будет повторена умеренное число раз.
Как его прочитать в php? Я проверил весь $_POST и нет там ничего.

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Попробуйте переформулировать

Comment: @E_p, Переформулировал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда боту пишут сообщение, на сервер посылается post-запрос с JSON. Чтобы его получить на сервере, нужно объявить что-то типа

```
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); // получаем JSON
```

В php-файле, которому адресован запрос. Потом, чтобы вытащить оттуда данные, пишем что-то типа

```
    $data->{'message'}->{'text'}; // вернет текст сообщения боту
    $data->{'message'}->{'chat'}->{'id'}; // вернет ID отправителя
```

Чтобы отправить ответ, можно сделать так

```
    file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/botЗДЕСЬ ТОКЕН БОТА/sendMessage?chat_id=ID ПОЛУЧАТЕЛЯ&text=ТЕКСТ СООБЩЕНИЯ);
```

Почитайте документацию к telegram API, там все написано

Comment: Спасибо! Работает

Comment: А как при отправке сообщения сделать перенос строки? \n превратилась в _

Comment: Добавил urlencode() и \n заработал. Теперь вопрос, как прочитать сообщение предпоследнее, чтобы создать цепочку типа /newpost потом бот пишет какой заголовок, ты пишешь заголовок, потом пишет картинку какую прикрепить ты ссылку на картинку и пост готов

Comment: Чтобы получить предпоследнее сообщение, пробуйте сохранить его на сервере, когда придет JSON с этим сообщением. Других вариантов в методах API я не нашел

Comment: Попробую. А как отправлять боту ссылку на картинку чтобы она не стала картинкой? У меня бот не знает как работать с файлом картинки, он ждет ссылки а телеграмм ее в картинку

Comment: Ну вроде ссылка на картинку должна быть в post запросе к серверу

Comment: Ссылки в post не было, нужно было идти к ['message']['photo'][3]['file_id'] и с этим на сайт получая json с названием файла. 3 в массиве это самое большое разрешение. А потом надо было идти на https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path> чтобы получить саму картинку... Теперь еще разобраться бы как сделать меня у клавиатуры.